# Emergency stop behavior - state of normally open switch when activated

Tags: switches, button, latching

I am using and emergency stop in an application. It is a push button with a twist release. I have the main circuit connected to the normally closed side and a detection circuit wired to the normally open side.

When the stop is activated, the normally closed switch of course opens and remains open (until I twist release the stop).

However, the normally open switch closes only momentarily. Do emergency stops exist in which the normally open switch will remain closed until twist released. If so, what keyword should I look for in searching for such an emergency stop?

Comment: That's unusual (I think). Are you sure? I think I remember that most emergency stops can have 2 circuits normally closed that latch open. You can use that for your detection circuit. What's downstream?

Comment: This one only has one normally open circuit (the button has for pins, two for the normally closed switch and two for the normally open). The normally open circuit is 5V from an Arduino, the NO switch and a 10K pull-down resistor. This is is wired to a digital in pin of the Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that the N.O. is not momentary. If it truly is then read the data sheet to find the truth about any limit switch.

What I think is happening is the "wetting current" and/or the "sealing current" is not being met by the detection circuit.

Some switch manufacturers will specify these two parameters, but not always. You may have to modify the detection circuit to draw several tens of milliamps to maintain the contact.

Search for these parameters.

---

Switches also suffer from "bouncing" on contact or separation. It will ultimately settle to closed on contact. The detection circuit may have todeal with this.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the wetting/sealing current for the switch. I forgot to also mention that the detection circuit does pick up the momentary closing of the NO switch. It also doesn't bounce. Would this change your thinking about the wetting/sealing current?

Comment: @Siva All switches bounce even if it isn't visible. There may be enough force on the first contact, but not on the others. This would not change my ensuring there is enough wetting/sealing current..

Comment: I will try to increase the current in the detection circuit to a few tens of milliamps (basically power it from a different source that can provide more current and use a smaller pull-down resistor), and see what happens. I will post back when I have been able to try that.

Answer (score 0):

When a latching-type, E-stop, mushroom push-button switch is actuated, the 'NC' as well as the 'NO' contacts remain latched till the switch is reset with a twist of the mushroom button.

It's apparent that the 'NO' contact is defective and needs replacement.

Should it be a low voltage / current / contact tarnish issue, a relay with gold-plated contacts would solve the problem.

[image]